# parallel programming in C with openmp

Tags: c, parallel-processing

Right now I am learning about parallel programming in C with openmp and now I have stumbled upon the following problem. I have a simple for loop which I want to parallelize. Using openmp, I thought the following code should do the job

```
unsigned long int teller_groot;
int               boel = 0;
int               k    = 0; 
int               l    = 1;
unsigned long int sum2;
int               thread_id;
int               nloops;

#pragma omp parallel private(thread_id, nloops)
{   
    sum2 = 0;
    #pragma omp for
        for (teller_groot=1000000; teller_groot<1000000000000; teller_groot++)
        {
            boel = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 78498; i++)
            {
                if (floor(teller_groot / array[i]) == teller_groot / array[i])                    
                {
                   boel = 1; 
                   break;
                }
            }

            if (boel == 0)
            {
               sum2 = sum2 + teller_groot;
            }

            if (sum2 >= 1000000000)
            {
               sum2 = sum2 - 1000000000;
            }

            if (k == 10000000)
            {
               printf("%d, ", l);
               l++;
               k = 0;
            }

            k++;
        }

        thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

        printf("Thread %d performed %d iterations of the loop.\n", thread_id, nloops);
}
```

The code

```
if (k == 10000000)
{
    printf("%d, ",l);
    l++;
    k = 0;
}

k++;
```

is just for me to know how far in the loop we are. If I run the program, it doesn't print anything, meaning it does not calculate anything. What is wrong with the code then? Thanks.

Comment: Please fix the indentation and use of white-space; it looks very bad!

Comment: @meaning-matters sorry, LPs has edited so I hope it does look OK now.

Comment: Is the last `printf` performed?

Comment: @LPs No, it just get's stuck

Comment: @Badshah Almost OK; I finished the job. Why do you use Dutch words?

Comment: You comment below that it does not do anything. But where does it get stuck? You could supply much more details.

Comment: @meaning-matters If I make k a private variable, then my program still doesn't print any value of l (which should give an indication how far the computation is). What more details do you need? I tried to do this computation for smaller numbers, i.e. teller_groot=10 up to teller_groot<100, but then it gives nonsense, meaning the values for sum2 in different threads are way too large. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: What's in `array`?  The code is not complete..

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variable `k` (among others) outside the openmp `for` loop.  When variables are declared outside parallel regions they have shared scope by default. This means all of the threads you use will be checking and writing to the same `k` variable, which could result in race conditions.

If you want to write to the same variable `k` with different threads you could use locks or atomic updates to produce the behaviour you want.

Otherwise, declare `k` as a private variable in the `#pragma` statement at the beginning of the parallel region:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(thread_id, nloops, k)
```

A good primer is available here:  http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/

Comment: I made all the variables private (also k) but it still doesn't do anything. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm writing an answer.

Which part of your code exactly gets stuck? (by *stuck* do we mean it takes an awful lot of time?)

because:

```
            if (floor(teller_groot / array[i]) == teller_groot / array[i])                    
            {
               boel = 1; 
               break;
            }
```

What you do is floor the result of (lets say to make it simple) 22/41 = 0.536 to => 0.5 and then check whether 0.536 == 0.5 and this does not equal so the command *break* might not get executed, depending on what is in *array* which you have not specified.

Also, a lot of your variables are shared including *array*, that might make a difference as well and the variable *nloops* is not specified (unless somewhere above the code you've shown)

check this pdf about openmp:
http://openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.Examples.pdf

EDIT:
btw, try flushing the buffer after printf(): *fflush(stdout)*